# HTML won't render using Javax

Tags: java, html, jakarta-mail

Any ideas why this isn't getting interpreted? I use a StringBuilder.append() to construct email & send it off, it's displaying as text. Here's a snippet.

```
    notificationEmail.append("Mr. " +salesOpsInfo[1]+ " " + salesOpsInfo[2] + '\n'); 
    notificationEmail.append(salesOpsInfo[0] + '\n');
    notificationEmail.append( "\n\n");
    notificationEmail.append("Dear Mr. "+ salesOpsInfo[2] + ","  + "\n");

    notificationEmail.append("" + '\n');
    notificationEmail.append(EndOfLicenseRenewal.eolTextBeforeTable());
    NotificationUtil.**sendMail**(salesOps_email_list, attachmentList, subject, salesOpsEmail.toString(), "eolnotification@DOMAIN.com", "mail.MYSERVER.com", false);
```

sendMail is the standard way of sending ..

```
        try
    {
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        if ((from != null) && (!from.equalsIgnoreCase(" "))) {
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        }
        InternetAddress[] address = new InternetAddress[recipients.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < recipients.size(); i++)
        {
            String rec = (String)recipients.get(i);
            if ((rec != null) && (!rec.equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
                address[i] = new InternetAddress((String)recipients.get(i));
            }
        }
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
        msg.setSubject(subject);


        MimeBodyPart mbpMessage = new MimeBodyPart();
        **mbpMessage.setContent(message, "text/html");**
        mbpMessage.setHeader("Content-ID", "<memememe>");


        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
        mp.addBodyPart(mbpMessage);
        if (attachments != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < attachments.size(); i++)
            {
                MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();


                FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource((String)attachments.get(i));
                mbp.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
                mbp.setFileName(fds.getName());
                mbp.setHeader("Content-ID", "<memememe>");

                mp.addBodyPart(mbp);
            }
        }
        msg.setContent(mp);


        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        Transport.send(msg);
```

As i understand it (text/html) should properly send it how i want.. instead in the email i get

```
you may contact our dedicated team at <u>eolnotification@DOMAIN.com </u>
```

EDIT : 
just tried and they don't work either.

```
        mbpMessage.setContent(message, "text/html");
        mbpMessage.setHeader("Content-ID", "text/html");
```

.saveChanges() doesn't seem to exist for MimeBodyPart

Answer (score 0):

Try calling mbpMessage.saveChanges() after you set the content.